# Having problems when adding module Navigation with ReactNative 0.65.1

Tags: react-native, npm, navigation

I'm trying to add module BottomNavigation and DrawerNavigation. I did download the module package successfully. I conducted import createBottomTabNavigator() or createDrawerNavigator() then i received  error notify as shown below.

[image]

**Can anyone help me?**

### Update:

I installed them by `npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs`.

And my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from '../Component/Home';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function BottomNav(){
    return(
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code snippets with how you imported the modules and how did you initialised them?
Also how you installed them

Also did you `pod install` and `./gradlew clean` after install?

Comment: @poPaTheGuru i installed them by `npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs`

Comment: did you `pod install` and `./gradlew clean` after install?

Also you should try to `npm run start --clear-cache` the server again

Comment: @poPaTheGuru I have not.Excume,can you for me know syntax of them?

Comment: add these 2 lines in your `package.json`: `"clean-ios": "cd ios && rm -rf build/ && pod install && cd ..",
    "clean-android": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd .. && npx jetify"`

and after every package that you install in your app, you should run `yarn clean-ios` and `yarn clean-android` or `npm run clean-ios` and `npm run clean-android` and after you clean the project, run again `npm run ios` and `npm run android` and if your code is alright, the app should be too

Comment: In my package.json. Where do I add 2 lines? "scripts", "dependencies","devDependencies" or "jest"

Comment: in `scripts` object

Comment: I did as same. When i run `npm run clean-android` and then i receive notify.

Comment: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! GreatFood@0.0.1 clean-android: `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd .. && npx jetify`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the GreatFood@0.0.1 clean-android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-

Comment: be sure that you are in the same directory with `package.json`

Comment: I'm sure. Because i'm running in terminal of vscode

Answer (score 1):

react native 0.65.1 had some issues with reanimated library. thats why happens, also i got same issue.

Comment: Exactly. With drawer navigation so reanimated library has issue. And bottom tabs so issue as shown above

Comment: @ChiếnNguyễnVăn i solved this with following steps: 


1 - Delete reanimated and other depencys about bottom tabs from your package.json and delete package-lock.json
2 - ` cd android && gradlew clean`
3 - Open android studio and wipe your device 
4 - install reactnavigator with yarn `yarn add @react-navigation/native` `yarn add react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context` `yarn add @react-navigation/bottom-tabs`
5 - Rerun your project